# What techniques were used to make the model's legs so skinny in this photograph?

Tags: technique, perspective

I'm just now learning about photography so I still know very little. I came across [this](http://s27.postimg.org/h0icqp8g3/781724985974258603_178890701.jpg) photograph, which looks very abnormal to me, and would appreciate it if someone could tell me about the techniques used to achieve that effect.

The thighs look disproportionately long (and thin), giving the impression they've been lengthened. I'd like to know how it was done.
[Here](http://s27.postimg.org/g3dcrho8z/778315131326757662_178890701.jpg)'s a more normal photograph of the same legs for comparison.

Comment: This question is a good example of why external links are discouraged, neither of the links above are working, so this question is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of using wide angle objective and corresponding viewing angle (tilted).

For the second photo: short upper dress and lines crossing legs (black dress, briefs' legs) are important as well

Comment: The lighting also contributes to the illusion ... See how the highlights on the top of the leg tend to make the leg appear to be skinnier.